# Combining Confidence Interval and custom Poisson in scipy or numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, math, scipy

I would like to use Poisson **(custom)** with a Confidence Interval. Is there a way to combine the two or similar? `scipy` or `numpy` are both fine whichever you choose.

IMPORTANT: I would need something where I could consider the specific Poisson cases with One, Two, Three

This is the code I use for a classic `Confidence Interval`

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st
  
data = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3,
         3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10]

x = st.t.interval(confidence=0.90, df=len(data)-1,
               loc=np.mean(data),
               scale=st.sem(data))

print(x)
```

This is the code I use for `custom Poisson`

```
average = 1.43

Zero = ((average ** 0) * 2.7182818284 ** (-average)) / 1 * 100
One = ((average ** 1) * 2.7182818284 ** (-average)) / 1 * 100
Two = ((average ** 2) * 2.7182818284 ** (-average)) / 2 * 100
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to calculate the mean and standard error for your Poisson distribution and then use the appropriate critical values from the Poisson distribution to find the confidence interval.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st

average = 1.43

# Calculate the mean and standard error for the Poisson distribution
mean = average
standard_error = np.sqrt(average)

confidence_level = 0.90

lower_critical_value = st.poisson.ppf((1 - confidence_level) / 2, mu=mean)
upper_critical_value = st.poisson.ppf(1 - (1 - confidence_level) / 2, mu=mean)

# Calculate the confidence interval
confidence_interval = (mean - lower_critical_value, mean + upper_critical_value)
```

Comment: Your code is clear, except for one thing: as you can see I calculate Poisson for One, Two and Three. I customized Poisson. In your code, what did you use Poisson for? I read "/2", so did you use Poisson for "Two"? (how did I use it?). which Poisson do lower critical value and upper critical value refer to? (my One, Two or Theree?). I do not understand

Comment: Can you modify your code with my modified Poisson (One, Two, Three) please? I'm not understanding how you use Poisson in your code, because I need it differentiated with One, Two, Three

Comment: In the code I provided, I used the Poisson distribution to calculate the critical values for the confidence interval, and those critical values are used for the entire distribution, not specifically for "One," "Two," or "Three."

Comment: In a Poisson distribution, the mean and variance are equal, and the critical values for a confidence interval are based on the Poisson distribution's properties. When you calculate the lower and upper critical values using st.poisson.ppf(), you are obtaining values for the entire distribution, not just for specific values like "One," "Two," or "Three."

Comment: The output of your code, therefore, indicates that the minimum critical value is 0% and the maximum critical value is 4%.

I was looking for something else, I wasn't looking for this, I wasn't looking for this result, so I didn't really understand what the critical values 0 and 4 of the average 1.43 are. Having an average of 1.43, what do the minimum and maximum critical values indicate? Can you explain better what 0 and 4 are in relation to the average please? For example if upper_critical_value is 4, what does it mean in relation to 1.43? Thank you